# Is it possible to have different targets for touches in different locations?

Tags: ios, swift

I have subclassed `UISegmentedControl` and added a special shape on its layer to be able to move the segmented control by tapping on this shape.

The problem is that I also implemented the "value changed" event for the `UISegmentedControl`.

Is it possible to say that when there is a tap on the segmented control, the "value changed" event is triggered and when it's on the shape on the layer (I have the frame, so I can find out if the tap was made within the shape), another target is triggered?

UPDATE:

Okay to avoid any misunderstanding with layers & co, let's imagine I have a `UIView`. If I tap on the left half of the view, I trigger an action, if I tap on the right half, I trigger another action.

Comment: A layer can't receive a touch event only `UIResponder`.

Comment: I know that but I can override `pointInside(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?)`and make it looks like I tap on the layer. Anyway that's not the question. Can I trigger two different actions depending on where the tap was done.

Comment: Yes, you can override `pointInside` method, but a touch event returns only a Hit-Test View in UIKit this means of only one *UIResponder* responding a touch event. However, you can manually trigger multiple action as you said

Comment: How? By calling my actions in `pointInside`?

Comment: Do you want to trigger two actions or trigger another action when the event is triggered on the shape?

Comment: No, two different action. What I would like is when one item of the segmented control is tapped, then the "value changed" is triggered, but if I tap within the bounds of the shape on my layer, then another action is triggered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have implemented a subclassed `UISegmentedControl`:

```
class MySegmentedControl: UISegmentedControl {

    var subLayer: CALayer?

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

        if let subLayer = subLayer {
            let touch = touches.first as! UITouch
            let point = touch.locationInView(self)

            if subLayer.frame.contains(point) {
                println("tapped on subLayer")
            } else {
                super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)
            }
        } else {
            super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)
        }
    }

}
```

Here is my test code:

```
// ViewController.swift

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let control = MySegmentedControl(items: ["One", "Two", "Three"])
    control.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 300, width: 200, height: 30)
    control.addTarget(self, action: "valueChanged", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
    view.addSubview(control)

    let subLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    subLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
    subLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 30)
    control.layer.addSublayer(subLayer)

    control.subLayer = subLayer
}

func valueChanged() {
    println("test")
}
```

I hope that will helps you.

Comment: I totally forgot about `touchesBegan`. Thanks!